# Append an argument from argv as null terminated array into an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pipe

I'm writing a program that's supposed to take multiple commands and pipe the output of one command into the input of the next command.

I'm trying to format my arguments from argv[] into an array of char arrays in C so I can then use it with execvp. Please let me know how to fix this or if there is another way to do this. Also, if someone could explain the variable n, that would really help. Thank You!!

```
  //input: ./example ls cat
  int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

    //how I want to format my arguments
    char *commands[][argc] = {
          {argv[1], NULL},
          {argv[2], NULL},
          {"ls", NULL},
          {"cat", NULL}
      };
  
    //the problem
    for(int m=1; m<argc ;m++)
    {
      char *arg[2] = {argv[m], NULL};
      //how do I input arg into commands?
    }

    //?
    size_t n;
    n = sizeof(commands) / sizeof(*commands);

    ...

    //ending goal
     execvp(commands[i][0], commands[i]);
}
```

Comment: Note: Character constants like `"ls"` are stored in read-only memory. You cannot copy over them.

Comment: What is `strcpy(*commands[m],*arg);` even trying to do? That code doesn't make any sense to me. Why are you copying into your command table? Is the goal here to expand from the given `argv` input into a structure like `commands`? If so, no `strcpy` is required. Just `calloc()` and populate with the pointers you're given. I also doubt you'd need a whole structure like that. You can create them as necessary before the `execvp` call.

Comment: Remember, you **must** `fork()` before calling `execvp` or your whole process goes away.

Comment: Note: `n` is just a way of computing the length of an array like `commands[]` which leaves the length otherwise unspecified.

Comment: when I hardcode it with argv[1] and argv[2] it works, but I want to be able to put all arguments in this format.

This is just a portion of the code, there is a fork where the ... is.

Comment: So n is equivilant to the length of an array in c++?

Comment: In C++ you have tools like `std::vector` which help a lot, but if you're using C-style arrays, then you're stuck with computations like that just the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to initialize `commands` when you declare it. You can fill in the `NULL` second element in the loop.

You can't assign to an array, so just assign to each element individually.

```
    char *commands[argc-1][2];
  
    //the problem
    for(int m=1; m<argc ;m++)
    {
      commands[m-1][0] = argv[m];
      commands[m-1][1] = NULL;
    }
```